# How do I build a custom object that consists of 2 custom objects for an expanding cell?

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

I am following along this [tutorial here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ClrSpJ3txAs) for collapsing UITableViewCells and the mechanics are quite straight forward but I am not quite sure how to populate my model arrays from Firestore. He has manually created the data for demo purposes so naturally as a beginner, I am stumbling since instead of that I am making a network call to Firebase.

My data structure is simple. The base collection (which would populate the title of the cell) extracts data from here: db.collection("Insurance_Plans") and contains the following strings:
- Holder name
- Holder contact etc.

And each insurance holder has multiple properties insured and this is the sub-collection i.e. db.collection("Insurance_Plans").document(planId).("Insured_Property") and data model consists of strings such as:
- Property type
- Property address etc.

What I am doing is creating the main struct:

```
struct cellData {
    var opened = Bool()
    var plans = [Plan]()
    var properties = [Properties]()
}
```

and in the class itself I declare an instance of it it as:

```
var tableViewData = [cellData]()
```

Then I query the insurance meta data (which has its own function) as follows:

```
db.collection("Insurance_Plans").getDocuments() {
            documents, error in

            guard let snapshot = documents else {
                let error = error
                print("Error fetching documents results: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }

            let results = snapshot.documents.map { (document) -> Plan in
                if let plan = Plan(dictionary: document.data(), id: document.documentID) {
                    self.plansArray.append(plan)
                    self.loadPropertyData(planId: document.documentID) // another function where property details are queried
                    return plan
                } else {
                    fatalError("Unable to initialize type \(Plan.self) with dictionary \(document.data())")
                }
            }

            self.plansArray = results

            self.plansDocuments = snapshot.documents

            self.plansTableView.reloadData()
        }
```

Then I query the properties in each plan as such:

```
db.collection("Insurance_Plans").document(planId).collection("Properties").getDocuments() { documents, error in

        guard let snapshot = documents else {
            let error = error
            print("Error fetching documents results: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }

        let results = snapshot.documents.map { (document) -> Property in
            if let property = Property(dictionary: document.data()) {
                return property
            } else {
                fatalError("Unable to initialize type \(Property.self) with dictionary \(document.data())")
            }
        }

        self.propertiesArray = results

        self.propertiesDocuments = snapshot.documents

        self.ordersTableView.reloadData()
    }
```

My question then is how do I enter the insurance meta data and the subsequent properties data into a cellData object and where do I do this?